# MSS repeats frames when recording computer screen

Tags: python, opencv, python-mss

I am trying to record the screen on my MacBook pro and store it in a video file. This isn't the end goal but this is the first step and I am noticing whatever I set my writing framerate to, I only get half of those in my final video. e.g. if I set it to 30, I'd get a video saved in 30fps but each frame would be repeated. frame 1 and 2 would be the same, frame 3 and 4 would be the same; so on and so forth. So I only get 15 frames.

I have already tried setting the framerate to 60 or 120, it gives me the same result. Whereas when I record my screen using a professional utility such as QuickTime, I get the recording as it should be, with no repeated frames and such.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

bbox = {'top': 270, 'left': 100, 'width': 600, 'height': 150}

sct = mss()

#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/Users/vipulrajan/Downloads/DinoGame/output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 60.0, (1200,300), isColor=0)

while 1:

    sct_img = sct.grab(bbox)
    im = np.array(sct_img)[:,:,2] #converting the image to grayscale

    out.write(im)
```

I have also tried adding and removing the cv2.waitKey function to the code and doesn't make any difference. Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Hm it seems that this code works as expected. Perhaps could you try it and post the video to help us understand what you see?

```py
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from mss import mss

frame_rate = 30
width, height = 600, 150
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',
                      cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
                      frame_rate,
                      (width, height),
                      isColor=0)
bbox = {'top': 270, 'left': 100, 'width': width, 'height': height}

with mss() as sct:
    start = time.monotonic()
    while 'capturing':
        im = np.array(sct.grab(bbox))[:,:,2]  # Convert to grayscale
        out.write(im)
        time.sleep(1 / frame_rate)

        if time.monotonic() - start > 3:  # 3 seconds
            break

out.release()
```